# MainActivityBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater()) page is not updated

Tags: android, android-databinding

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    Main2Binding binding1 =  Main2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    User user = new User("Test", "User");
    MyHandlers myHandlers = new MyHandlers(this);
    MyStringUtils myStringUtils=  new MyStringUtils();
    binding1.setUser(user);
    binding1.setHandlers(myHandlers);
}
```

Page is not updated,

```
MainActivityBinding binding1 = DataBindingUtil.setContentView (this, R.layout.main_activity); there is no problem
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind layout with your `Activity` you need to use

```
MainActivityBinding binding1 = DataBindingUtil.setContentView (this, R.layout.main_activity);
```

But when you are working with `Fragment` you can use inflate

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MainActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.main_activity, container, false);
}
```

**Note : Binding name will be based on layout name, if layout file name is activity_main.xml then your binding will be ActivityMainBinding.**

Answer (score 8):

The right way using DataBinding via inflate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    //setContentView(R.layout.main2); //<---comment it
    Main2Binding binding1 = Main2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding1.getRoot());
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the true answer for this question.